# Dynamically loading json file by package name (Typescript)

Tags: json, typescript

I am trying to write a small browser game in Typescript. So to start, I have a **Scenario** class that would need to load characters' dialogues based on scenario names.
Here is how the **Scenario** class looks like:

```
export class Scenario extends Entity{

  public characters: Character[] = [];

  constructor(
    public readonly scenarionName: string,
    public readonly startDialogueId: string
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public awake() {
    this.loadCharacters();
  }

  private loadCharacters(){
    this.characters = [];
    // FIXME how can I dynamically load dialogues based on scenario name? 
  }
}
```

My idea was to have dialogues stored in JSON files, which would then be loaded based on the scenario name, which would also be a package name. Here how it looks:

[image]

In this case, I want to dynamically load 'npc.json' and 'player.json' into **Scenario** class based on the scenario name which in this case is a 'test'. In the future, there would be more scenarios and I would like to avoid hard coding.
Can this be done in such a way and if so, how?

EDIT: the game would run in the browser.

Comment: If you're going to add the files to src like this, why not keep them as TypeScript? It'll be less prone to bugs, easier to edit, refactor, etc.

Comment: Is this supposed to run in the browser or on the backend?

Comment: @RichardDunn Answered your questions (see the EDIT part). Also good call with keeping them in the typescript. Maybe it is a better way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. Node is a backend runtime, browsers do not use Node, they use other runtimes/environments. Both interpret and execute JavaScript. You cannot say "in the browser (in the node environment)" - they are mutually exclusive, unless you are writing a library to target both. I assume you meant just the browser? If that's the case, the norm for dynamic data is to store it in a DB and serve/load it asynchronously.

Comment: @RichardDunn You are right. My bad. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fs` module to get the file names in a directory and read the contents of the files.

```
import fs from('fs');

export class Scenario extends Entity{

  public characters: Character[] = [];

  constructor(
    public readonly scenarionName: string,
    public readonly startDialogueId: string,
    scenarioPath: string
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public awake() {
    this.loadCharacters();
  }

  private loadCharacters(){
    this.characters = [];
    const dialoguesDir = `${this.scenarioPath}/${this.scenarioName}/dialogues/`;
    let dialogueContent;
    fs.readdirSync(dialoguesDir).forEach(filePath => {
       dialogueContent = fs.readFileSync(`${dialoguesDir}${filePath}`).toString();
    // Do something with contents
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's fine if this is Node, but it's not clear from the question if this is supposed to be executed in the browser or the backend.

Comment: Thanks, will try it!

Comment: @Christian No, because I will execute my code in browser so I can't use Node modules. However I did not specify this in questions before, so you could not know. Thanks.